# Email Tracking in PHP

Tags: php

I am currently working PHP, I want to track email status and update into my database such as who read the email or who opened?, who deleted?, who replied? and also When was the email opened/deleted/replied? Date and time.

I got the solution from online resources for open rate which i have been implemented.
but I want to know is there any possibility to find who deleted the email? which I have been sent. please share the idea or give the solution

Thanks for your reply in advance.

Comment: Straight off the bat, there's no way to know when someone deletes an email using a [web bug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_bug).

Answer (score 7):

The only information you can get is *who responded with a received or opened receipt* …

- Many email clients don't support these
- No email client sends them silently by default
- Many users will choose to refuse to allow one to be sent to you

…  and *how many times a given image has been requested from your server*. You can associate an image with a particular recipient in your database but:

- They might forward the email so someone else could be requesting the image
- Most email clients block images by default. Some filter out webbugs specifically.

There is no way to get a message in response to a deletion, reply, forward, etc.

In short: Emails are not spies.